# Get links in Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the following links in Beautiful Soup and I'm not exactly sure what the best way of doing this is. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever interested, I figured out how to do this:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = requests.get("http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html").text
def find_governor_races(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pattern = "http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/????/governor/??/*-*.html"

    links = []

    for option in soup.find_all('option'):
        links.append(option['value'])

    matched_links = []

    for link in links:
        if fnmatch(link, pattern):
            matched_links.append(link)

    return matched_links
```